# vs2010 XAML Find highlight is very fade

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, search

As you can see at the following picture when I search for a word with "Find Next" button the highlight on the word I'm searching is very faded and difficult to see.

[image]

but when I search it with F3 I can see the highlight better because it's on blue background.

[image]

Is there any way to apply the blue background also on "Find Next" button??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the setting you're looking for is Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Show Settings for Text Editor->Inactive Selected Text.

I switched mine to the red colour that you see in the screenshot below as a test but from your question description you'll want to set Inactive Selected Text to the same value as Selected Text.

[image]